# How to write png file to target directory from client side by flask

Tags: python, flask

I want to write to file from request.form["file"] but I can't do it.

My contact.html is here.

Client side code is like this...

```
<form action="contact" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Server side is like this

```
filestorage = request.files["file"]

print type(_file) #-> <FileStorage: u"__proto.png" ("img/png")>

# I tried below this , but it doesn't work.

f = open("tmp.png","wb")
f.write(filestorage)
```

I want to write this which is png file to  uploaded file somewhere. Do you have any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

You have the `save()` method of the `FileStorage` object, that lets you save the file content to disk:

```
file.save('/path/to/your/file')
```

Flask Documentation: http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage.save

A useful tutorial: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/fileuploads/

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to configure your upload folder

```
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = PATH_TO_UPLOAD_FOLDER
```

Then to save your file

```
f = request.files["file"]
f.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], 'tmp.png'))
```